# How to format [url=][/url] code or shortcode on a custom built website?

Tags: php

Well i need to make some kind of function or shortcode to format those type of links.

I am working on some website and parsing data from json format and inside that data there are link codes like this as a text.

So what i get inside json file is this:

```
[url=http://store.steampowered.com/app/901583/]GTA IV: Complete Edition[/url] includes Grand Theft Auto IV and Episodes from Liberty City.
```

So i use:

```
$json = file_get_contents('link file'); //to get json file
$file = json_decode($json, true); //to retrieve data as an array
```

What i get from this is:

```
Array
(
[6516] => Array
    (
        [success] => 1
        [data] => Array
            (
                [name] => Grand Theft Auto IV: Complete Edition
                [purchase_text] => [url=http://store.steampowered.com/app/901583/]GTA IV: Complete Edition[/url] includes Grand Theft Auto IV and Episodes from Liberty City.
            )

    )

)
```

The code is too big so i cut irrelevant text

And than i use:

```
$pobj[$package]['data']['purchase_text']; //where $package is package id(the number in array)
```

But this text is different for each json file and there might be multiple urls so i need some kind of universal solution

So how do i get these url links to format on my website as normal links? some kind of shortcode or what ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression such as

`\[url=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]`

This would pull the link and the title:

`preg_match('|\[url=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]|', $string, $matches);`

`$matches[1]` would be the link and `$matches[2]` would be the title:

`echo '<a href="' . $matches[1] . '">' . $matches[2] . '</a>';`

In response to the comment lets get a bit more complex:

This regex will be more accurate and match more than one url in the string:

`\[url=(https?:\/\/?[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]`

Comment: this could be solution but i don't know if it works if there are multiple urls in text, so i updated my question with a bit more informations.

Comment: Edited the answer in regards to your comment

Comment: well i couldn't make regex works, so i ended up with str_replace             $replace = array('[url=', ']', '[/url]');
            $replacement = array('<a href="', '" target="_blank">', '</a>'); str_replace($replace, $replacement, $purchase_text) where $purchase_text = $pobj[$package]['data']['purchase_text']; so it works with multiple links on page but i don't know what will happen if there is anything other wrapped.